# Decorator fundamentals (Closure) , how/why are function local arguments reusable without passing them in again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection, arguments, python-decorators

### Let's say I have the following code in python3:

```
def func(string):
    def wrapper():
        print("started")
        print(string)
        print("Ended")
    return wrapper


x = func('string argument')

print(x())
```

------------------------------- Commentary Below------------------
My output is as follows:

```
>>started
>>string argument
>>Ended
>>None
```

Can someone please explain how the line:

print(x())

is still able to access the string argument from the line:

```
x = func('string argument')
```

I thought once you pass an agruement into a fun and it runs, that all
of the function's variable are cleared out. Is this considered the topic of garbage collection in python?

I understand that x becomes an alias for wrapper,
but I don't see why the line:

```
print(x())
```

should run, especially since I'm not passing in
in an string a second time.

I share this because in previous experience I usually have to pass in arguments to make a function that requires arguments execute. To me it seems like the string arg is just hanging around and I'm able to use it in later line even though, I didn't pass anything in the second time.

```
print((x())
```

seems like a loophole in python's garbage collection, if I understand correctly.

Comment: What made you think that?

Comment: You'll want to read up on closures.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure

Comment: Not to disparage your question or anything, finding the above existing question might be difficult without having known the term, "closure". Your question may still be useful as a "signpost" to redirect others.